# Is "Windows-based PC" a correct term in American English?

Tags: word-choice, terminology

I am writing a support message to a customer support of an audio hardware vendor. I need to describe them that I am running Microsoft Windows as the main OS on my computer. Is "Windows-based PC" term it correct to describe a computer with say Windows XP installed?

An example of using the term:

- I am using the Audigy card with onboard firewire controller to connect my audio device to a Windows-based PC.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Windows-based PC* is ok, as is *Windows PC*. However, when writing support messages or bug reports, it's best to give as much pertinent information as possible. So tell them you have a PC with Windows XP.

(It may even help to tell what service pack has. Try and tell them exactly what you did when the problem occurred and if it's repeatable.)

Comment: This answer is fine, just a brief elaboration for the original poster: I am using the *Audigy 2 ZS* card with the *Creative Sound Blaster Audigy series driver 2.18.0017* on a PC running *Windows XP (SP3)*.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than calling it a Windows-based PC which sounds awkward though nobody will misunderstand you, you can simply call it a PC with Windows XP installed.